# Play youtube and facebook video by url

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

how i can play YouTube and Facebook video by url in html website. I'm going to build a event website where client will copy video url from YouTube or their Facebook.
   Here is html code:

```
Youtube Videos: <input name="vlinkop" type="radio" value="utube">

Facebook Video: <input name="vlinkop" type="radio" value="fvideo">

<input autofocus="true" class="form-control" type="url" name="txturl">
<input type="submit" name="btnsave" class="btn btn-info" value="Save" />
```

here video will display on page load:

```
      <?php
     if(!empty($result)){
       foreach($result as $video){
       ?>
       <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
         <iframe src="<?php echo $video->videourl;  ?>"></iframe>
       </div>
      <?php } } >
```

Comment: i don't know why people make it -1 always :(

Comment: Because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Almost no one will help you if you don't show a minimal effort

Comment: @BinarWeb, i described my problem what i want to do and few html code and php code.

Comment: _“i don't know why people make it -1 always”_ - only describing what you want is simply not enough here on this site. _You_ need to do some initial work and research/try something, and then you can come here with _specific_ questions. A mere “how can I”-question that doesn’t show any actual attempt or research efforts, to me simply is one out of the “in over their head” category. In that case, people need to go read up on the basics first IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look:

[Embedded Video & Live Video Player]

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player

Youtube:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/YOUR-YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE"
   width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

Replace YOUR-YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE with video code